# Linux Arch: dhcpcd fails to start wireless srvice though worked before

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, arch-linux

I have only wireless service on my computer (I cannot physically move it to reach Ethernet).

As I start Linux, I see an error message: (I replaced wlp0... with )

```
    [FAILED] Failed to start dhcpcd on <mywirelessinterface>. See 'systemctl status dhcpcd@<mywirelessinterface>.service’ for details.
```

Ok, I do that:

```
    # systemctl status dhcpcd@<mywirelessinterface>.service

    * dhcpcd@<mywirelessinterface>.service - dhcpcd on <mywirelessinterface>
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/system/system/dhcpcd@.service: enabled)
    Active: failed (Result: resources) since <recent date and time>
    Process: 2918 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dhcpcd -q -w %I (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

    <Current date and time> localhost system[1]: PID file /run/dhcpcd-<mywirelessinterface>.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
    <Current date and time> localhost system[1]: Failed to start dhcpcd on <mywirelessservice>.
    Failed to start dhcpcd on <mywirelesscervice>.
    <Current date and time> localhost system[1]: Unit dhcpcd@<mywirelessinterface>.service entered failed state.
```

When I start it manually with sudo su:

```
    # systemctl start dhcpcd@<mywirelessinterface>.service
```

it fails the same way:

```
      Job for dhcpcd@<mywirelessinterface>.service failed. See ‘systemctl status netctl@<mywirelessinterface>\x2<mynetworkname>.service’ and ‘journalctl –xn’ for details.
```

Here is what journal says:

```
    # journalctl -xn

    -- Logs begin at <date, time>, end at <date, time>. --
    <Current date and time> localhost dhcpcd[4366]: <mywirelessinterface> failed to start wpa_supplicant
    <Current date and time> localhost dhcpcd[4367]: <mywirelessinterface> sucessfully initialized wpa_supplicant
    Line 1062: unknown EAP method 'SIM'. You may need to add support for this EAP method during wpa_supplicant build time configuration. See README for more information.
    Line 1062: failed to parse eap 'SIM'.
    Line 1065: failed to parse network block.
    Line 1072: unknown EAP method 'PSK'. You may need to add support for this EAP method during wpa_supplicant build time configuration. See README for more information.
    Line 1072: failed to parse eap 'PSK'.
    Line 1076: failed to parse network block.
    Line 1108: unknown EAP method 'IKEV2'. You may need to add support for this EAP method during wpa_supplicant build time configuration. See README for more information.
    Line 1108: failed to parse eap 'IKEV2'.
    Line 1111: failed to parse network block.
    Failed to read or parse configuration 'etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf'.
    <Current date and time> localhost dhcpcd[213]: <mywirelessinterface>: waiting for carrier
    <Current date and time> localhost dhcpcd[213]: <myotherinterface>: waiting for carrier
    <Current date and time> localhost dhcpcd[213]: control command: /usr/sbin/dhcpcd -k <myotherinterface>
    <Current date and time> localhost dhcpcd[213]: <myotherinterface> removing interface
    <Current date and time> localhost kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): <mywirelessinterface>: link is not ready
    <Current date and time> localhost kernel: ieee80211 phy0: rt2800usb_entry_txstatus_timeout: Warning - TX status timeout for entry 10 in queue 0
    <Current date and time> localhost kernel: ieee80211 phy0: rt2800usb_entry_txstatus_timeout: Warning - TX status timeout for entry 10 in queue 0
    <Current date and time> localhost kernel: ieee80211 phy0: rt2800usb_entry_txstatus_timeout: Warning - TX status timeout for entry 10 in queue 0
```

I did try ip link, iw dev

```
     ip link set <mywirelessinterface> up
```

Did not help.
I have not played with /etc/dhcpcd.conf yet and I don't know if a wpa_supplicant configuration file exists. I just don't know what they are yet. Help!!!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it is a problem with wpa_supplicant: the default /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf is basically all about documentation, it is **not** a valid configuration file. The following is a simple example of a valid file:

```
 ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
 ap_scan=1
 fast_reauth=0
 network={
    ssid="WifiNetworkName"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    psk="WifiNetworkPassword"
    priority=5
 }
```

You may wish to keep the old version (just rename it to /etc/wpa_supplicant_old.conf, for instance) because it contains many useful examples.

Alternatively, you may make your life much simpler by installing a network manager: there are many, netctl, wicd, personally I prefer NetworkManager. You can find [in the Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager) all the instructions you need. Just remember to disable any other service trying to manage your connections for you, you can list all enabled services with the command

```
  sudo systemctl --type=service
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I have a wifi profile but it wouldn't start after I started `dhcpcd` on wired network.

To solve this trouble I disabled all `dhcpcd` and all `netctl` services and restarted the system; then it re-read the wifi profile and activate again

I hope this helps you, I used something similar to this:

```
sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd.service
sudo systemctl disable netctl.service
sudo reboot
```